# cp -Rdfp $source/* $dest/ wont copy .htaccess

Tags: cp

This command wont copy .htaccess files:

```
cp -Rdfp $source/* $dest/
```

Thanks

Comment: The problem is, that the wildcard (`*`) does not expand to hidden files (starting with `.`) by default. You should check the question from my previous comment for possible solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In bash, the `*` glob doesn't include hidden files ('dotfiles') by default - you can enable that explicitly by setting the `dotglob` shell option e.g.

```
shopt -s dotglob
cp -Rdfp $source/* $dest
```

You can unset the option after with `shopt -u dotglob`.

Alternatively, if `$dest` does not already exist, the much simpler

```
cp -Rdfp $source $dest
```

(avoiding the glob altogether) should work as well.